# Reading data from file into string

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file and put data into string. However the compiler is outputting this.

```
012  
345  
678  
����012345678
```

with the new lines. Can you explain what is happening?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
int main() {
  ofstream output("transform.out");
  ifstream input("transform.in"); 
  int num = 0;
  input >> num; 
  char tmp[num+1];
  char data[num * num +1];
  while(input >> tmp){
    cout << tmp << '\n';
    strcat(data, tmp);
  }
  cout << data; 
}
```

transform.in has this data

```
3
012
345
678
```

Comment: `char tmp[num+1];` is not valid C++. Use a vector or better yet std::string.

Comment: Does the code compile? When you say "the compiler is outputting" do you mean "the program is outputting"? What do you mean "with the newlines". Can you provide a full snippet of the output, that would help us understand the situation better.

Comment: The exercise requires use of c strings. Can you explain why that is not valid?

Comment: This `char tmp[num+1]` and this `char data[num * num +1]` are invalid syntaxes, the array size defined inside the square brackets must be a constant value.

Comment: what is the reason for disallowing variable length arrays.

Comment: It is simply disallowed by (standard) C++, it is the way the language is defined. Your code will not work with other compilers. There is a way to create variable length arrays, but that involves doing other things, which you can probably search yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that standard C++ does not support variable length arrays like `char data[num * num +1]` (`num` is not a constexpr). Your code compiles because you probably use a compiler with an extension supporting VLAs. For portable code, however, you'd need to use some dynamic data structures, e.g. a `vector`.

Anyway, you do not initialize `data`, such that your very first `strcat` might append a (valid) content of `tmp` to `data` that starts with garbage. Your output `����` is not a result of a newline but just that garbage to which the very first `strcat` appends your file contents.

`char data[num * num +1] = { 0 };` should solve this problem.